# Passing the argument from a previous step in sklearn pipelines

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline

I have a dataset with numerical and categorical features on which I am trying to fit a classifier. My idea was to preprocess the categorical data first using Pandas such that my dataset can be written as (to borrow MATLAB's concatenation notation)

X_train = [ X_train_num, X_train_cat ]

and

X_test = [ X_test_num, X_test_cat ].

To deal with numerical data, I did the following:

```
# define concatenation of arrays so we can assemble the various parts
# that are preprocessed differently in the pipelines
def concat(a1, a2):
    return np.concatenate((a1, a2), axis=1)

# pipeline to preprocess, reassemble, and fit our models
trainPipeline = Pipeline([
('preprocessing', numPipeline), # scale numerical data
('assembling', FunctionTransformer(concat, kw_args={'a2' : X_train[nominalFeatures]})), # wrong, but how?
('classifying', LogisticRegression())
])
```

The issue here is that when I pass X_train to the pipeline, it only extracts X_train_num to scale it in the first step, which is why I need to reassemble X_train_num_scaled with X_train_cat = X_train[nominalFeatures] together in the second step. The code above will obviously not work when I use X_test as an input for prediction unless I find a way to access the initial input from the first step and use that in the concatenation step.

I have tried to look at trainPipeline.steps[0] and down the list for the initial variable name but found nothing that could help me. What am I missing?

Comment: Use FeatureUnion

Answer (score 1):

As @Vivek Kumar states, you should implement `FeatureUnion()` method in order to construct that pipe. It is usually used to concatenate inputs to let the model train on the extended data. So, in your case the pipe should look as the following:

```
def concat(a1, a2):
    return np.concatenate((a1, a2), axis=1)

subpipe = Pipeline(
        [('concat', FunctionTransformer(concat, kw_args={'a2': X_train[nominalFeatures]})),
         ('preproc', numPipeline())])
union = FeatureUnion(
        [('prep_data', subpipe),
         ('raw_data', FunctionTransformer(concat, kw_args={'a1': X_train_num}))])
pipe = Pipeline(
        [('union', union),
         ('logreg', LogisticRegression())])
```

Then, you should be able to perform `pipe.predict(X_test, y)` provided X_test is already preprocessed.

---

---

Quickcheck: I applied `numPipeline()` function to **X_train[nominalFeatures]** and let **X_train_num** be as it is. I hope that is what you desire.

Comment: Make sure the result of `subpipe` and `second functionTransformer for a1`, both return an explicit 2-d array with same number of rows, otherwise the featureUnion will fail.

Comment: Yeah, right. Pipes likes these brought me some pain in the *** back in the days. Hope you're doing great, Vivek!

Comment: I was hoping to explicitly avoid using X_train or X_test in the concatenation step, otherwise `pipe.fit(X_test, y)` as written above ends up concatenating X_test with X_train, which does not make sense conceptually.

Comment: I meant `pipe.predict(X_test, y)` there, I am sorry. **X_test** should be already preprocessed in a way that your **pipe** may predict on it.

Comment: In other words, if your **pipe** ends up fitting on `((X_train_num, X_train[nominalFeatures]))`, then **X_test** must have the same structure logic.